Regarding the definition of negative variation
I am reading Stein and Shakarchi's measure theory textbook. Let $\nu$ be a signed measure taking values in $(-\infty, \infty]$. The negative variation is defined as $$\nu^{-}(E) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{2}(|\nu|(E)-\nu(E)), & \nu(E) < \infty\\ 0, & \nu(E) = \infty\end{cases}$$ I am having trouble showing that this is a measure. More specifically, let $\{E_{j}\}$ be a disjoint sequence of sets in the $\sigma$-algebra such that $\nu(\bigcup E_{j}) = \infty$. In this case, to have $$\nu^{-}(\bigcup E_{j}) = \sum \nu^{-}(E_{j})$$ we must show that $\nu^{-}(E_{j}) = 0$ for all $j$, but it is not at all clear to me how one would show this, especially for the case in which there is at least one $j$ such that $\nu(E_{j}) < \infty$.
I feel like I'm missing something trivial or misinterpreting the definition. Any help is appreciated.

I believe that the definition is incorrect. For instance, consider any extended $\mu$-integrable function $f$ with $\int f^{+}\text{d}\mu = \infty$ and such that $f < 0$ on a set of positive measures. The only way to justify the existence of $\nu^{-}$ (at least as far as I can see) is to use the Jordan decomposition theorem.
